# Want value of variable "fileName"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have following method and code for getting image path,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        fileName = [representation filename];
        NSLog(@"fileName : %@",fileName);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:nil];


    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.profileImg.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    profileImg.hidden = NO;

}
```

Now I want the value of fileName in another method that is,

```
- (IBAction)registerBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"fileName path = %@", fileName);
}
```

In log result I get "**null**"

In my .h file I have implement the fileName variable.

So how can I get the value of this variable?

Comment: when you called the button, it is immediately or some time delay

Comment: In my button call, after I press button it stores the field data to database @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Your `registerBtn` method must be get called after you completely pick the image(i.e. your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`) get called.

Second thing if you just want to set unique name to your image then you should use `time stamp`.

You can get metadata of picked image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` like,

```
   NSDictionary *metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

NSLog(@"%@", metadata);
```

then from meradata dictionary you can fetch value of `DateTimeOriginal` which will give pick date of media.